# How should I have handled this rejected edit

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

This [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19860081) got rejected by 2 reviewers (but approved by 1) with the following reason:

*This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.*

The PO of the question was asked to show some code. He did so, but posted it as an answer to his question.

I decided to add a new section to the question (marked as edit) and move the code to there. No code, nor content changed. I also voted to remove the answer.

How should I have handled this?

Comment: I would have edit/approved that.  I don;t think you needed the *edit:* heading. But great edit, keep it up...

Comment: OP Edited question after your edit was approved by @Undo and it is again without code example

Comment: Just another classic example of the edit review queue doing exactly the opposite of what it is intended to do.

Comment: I'm one of the original reviewers. Sorry about that! I must've only looked at the content itself and not the comment. I'll be sure to keep an eye out in the future for things like this.

Comment: @jhpratt No problem, I only posted this question to get feedback about how to become a better reviewer. We are all here to learn :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I retroactively approved your edit. Some people review too fast and/or don't read.

I was planning to say you should have made it clear in the edit summary what you did... but you did that. I don't have any further ideas on what you could have done better.

Comment: "I don't have any further ideas on what you could have done better."... besides "have better luck next time" :)

Comment: I suspect that people read edit summaries nowhere near as often as they should. I wonder if there is anything that could be done about that...

Comment: OP Edited question after that and removed code from question

Comment: I was going to say the same Re. making it clearer but the description is right there. I think the problem is due to the smaller font size. It makes the description less obvious, when really it's the most important thing there. The font should be at least the same size and weight as the question title.

Comment: Re. the OP undoing all the edits (As pointed out by Piro already) - what is the correct course of action regarding flagging etc?

Comment: @Scoots Rolled it back; thanks. An 'other' flag would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your suggested edit was mistaken for an audit.

When reviewing suggested edits, people see audits, which usually contain unintelligible nonsense generated by the system. The purpose of audits is to check that people are paying attention when reviewing, and press "reject" correctly when being presented by nonsense.

Your edit summary contained a typo ("PO", while the correct word is "OP"). People try to discern nonsense (audits) as quickly as possible, so they probably took the whole thing to be nonsense.

> I see nonsense in edit summary.
>
> I see that the edit adds much code that I don't want to analyze.
>
> Therefore, this is vandalism/audit, so I reject the edit.

The whole reasoning above probably took just a few seconds, because trying to understand audits is a frustrating experience, and people want to waste as little time doing it as possible.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my mistake in the OP abbreviation , I wasn't aware of that.