# An editor rolled back my rollback on my question. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, rollbacks

A little more than two weeks ago, I posted ['6 high severity vulnerabilities' in a fresh Create React App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75960550).

Here is [revision 1 of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75960550/1).

And for your convenience, here is [the Markdown source of revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8de85fe0-b9f3-4be0-ab14-a8cf65081aa3/view-source).

An editor made a rather extensive edit of my post that I didn't like:

1. They removed my summary of the six actions I had tried that didn't work.
2. They removed the `package.json` file I had included, without which it is impossible to reproduce my example (with the exact package version(s) I used).
3. Most of all, they removed the very question I was asking: "How can I *force* `package.json` to use version `2.1.1` of `nth-check`?"

So I rolled it back. I was already baffled by the above edit, when the editor rolled back my rollback. Here is [the timeline of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75960550/timeline).

What should I do now?

Since [comments are meant to be ephemeral](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312002), here are two of the question's comments:

> Thanks for suggesting an edit to my question. However, I cannot accept an edit that *removes* the `package.json` from it. The `package.json` is what makes my post [a "minimal, complete and verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please don't suggest edits that remove such vital information! The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15806152) that you suggest that my question is a duplicate of, is missing precisely this information.
> – [Henke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9213345)
> [Apr 8 2023 at 7:39](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75960550#comment133981976_75960550)

> The command you run already minimally reproduces it. If you'd like to go the other route, package file then install, only *one* dependency is needed: react-scripts (and that doesn't necessitate restoring the aesthetic catastrophe that was the rest of your first attempt). And no you don't "own" the post, see [stackoverflow.com/help/editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) for a better understanding of the collaborative model here.
> – [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)
> [Apr 8 2023 at 7:49](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75960550/6-high-severity-vulnerabilities-in-a-fresh-create-react-app#comment133982050_75960550)

Comment: "_And no you don't "own" the post_" I'm mean, literally speaking, in the SEDE database, the author of a post is referred to as the "Post Owner". It's not wrong to call it that way. But they are correct in pointing to the guidance in /help/editing.

Comment: "*He removed the package.json file I had included and without which it is impossible to reproduce my example (with the exact package version(s) I used).*" note that the versions you had were already insufficient to accurately reproduce the problem. They were all marked with `^` which means that running `npm install` with a dependency like `^1.2.3` might actually install version 1.5.17. Depends on *when* the installation takes place - the higher most version matching *the major* part of the number (the first one) would be installed.

Comment: If a dependency is published with a higher minor and/or patch version, that newer dependency would be used. It might or might not have the same problems. It might or might not have other problems. Thus the package.json with caret range is exceedingly likely to not lead to stable reproduction of a build and this chance grows with time. A year from now, a lot of dependencies would have received updates and with those, the resulting build using caret ranges in package.json.

Comment: The edit for the most part seems helpful to me, it made the question more concise, if your main objection is "_he removed the very question I was asking_" why not add that sentence back in?

Comment: @VLAZ,
whether or not to have the caret (^) in package.json, can be discussed and decided by whoever is interested in reproducing.
Such a decision cannot be made if the package.json is completely missing, though.

Comment: Still, you wrote in your initial question: "*Putting the package.json in an empty folder and then running npm install is all it takes to have a minimal, complete and verifiable example.*" what that *should have* read is "*Putting the package.json in an empty folder and then running npm install is all it takes to have a minimal, complete and verifiable example. **Only valid today***" the bolded part is what I added to make the statement correct. It does also highlight a huge issue with the initial question as it might not be reproducible by anybody who's not trying this right now.

Comment: "The-editor" is easily identified by looking at the revision history. With that said, ultimately the editor's improvements were valid, minus removing a single sentence that highlighted your question. Since that question is in the current revision, what came before it, isn't material since you ultimately received an answer to your question. In the end your question needed to be improved so it could be helpful to the entire community. In fact the question did remain in the second revision, only slightly reworded, and significantly improved in my opinion.

Comment: The edit introduced "How can I *force* NPM to use version `2.1.1` of `nth-check`?" which seems to be equivalent (maybe even better due to generality) to "How can I *force* `package.json` to use version `2.1.1` of nth-check? ". Is the change from "`package.json`" to "NPM" really sufficient to say the question was removed?

Comment: I don't mind being cited, it's visible in the history anyway. The question as stated was meaningless - you can't force `package.json` to _do_ anything, it's a static text file. The behaviour is the file plus whatever's interpreting it, which in this case was NPM (but could be e.g. Yarn). And I wouldn't have any problem with a _minimal_ package file instead of the command, but what was posted wasn't one (just the one that happened to be _created_ by that command).

Comment: Independent of all that, [look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75960550/) what [the weird syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) is doing. It may need very stern directions.

Comment: It's closed as a duplicate and I've thrown a temporary lock on it to limit Meta effect. As another mod noted on your flag, the edits do not appear to be destructive

Comment: @Machavity,
can you please reach out to me concerning the flag I raised some 5–15 minutes ago?
(It's on an issue not to be discussed publicly.)
I don't have time to go through it today.
Tomorrow would be better.
(The day after tomorrow might be even better.)

Answer (score 16):

Holy wall of text, Batman.

So this is going to be based more in the Stack Overflow-side of things, rather than if the edit added or removed information unnecessarily or incorrectly.  Basically... **you had a *lot* of stuff** in your original question, and an edit trimmed it down.

From what I can tell, the vast majority of your question's intent is preserved and presented in a more laconic fashion, rather than multiple numbered sections, and even a *references* section. No one asks a question with a *references* section.

You're reading this requirement too literally:

> Revision 2 violates the classical Stack Overflow request to always make sure that what you did is reproducible.

Yes, we want this to be reproducible, but it has to be reproducible in a minimal way.  That is to say, use the fewest lines of code to reproduce your issue as possible.  In the minimum, you're looking at generating a new project and trying to pinpoint the dependency(ies) that are vulnerable.

...do you really need a whole wall of text to explain that to someone who's more expert in the field?

Comment: And the beauty in minimizing the reproducible example is if you isolate the mistake in a smaller space, you, and everyone else, is more likely to spot it. In the end a minimal example should be the bug, the whole bug, and nothing but the bug, and if you can get your example down to that level of perfection, you've certainly found the bug. You might not know why it's a bug or how to fix it, but you can't miss the sucker. Such an example attracts high quality answers (or closure as a duplicate of an existing question with one) and everybody wins.

Comment: **No one asks a question with a *references* section.**
– I did.

Comment: @Henke:  Do you do that when you're asking questions of colleagues face to face?  That's kinda the point I'm making with that.

Comment: @user4581301 Sometimes it even convinces people to close the *existing* question as a duplicate of the *new* one, and re-route other closed questions to a new, better canonical.

Comment: *Do you do that when you're asking questions of colleagues face to face?*
– Of course, I do!
When you go to a conference, do you talk about the weather?
I prefer to talk about the hottest papers or references that other experts and researchers in my field are buzzing about.
Why should Stack Overflow be any different?

Answer (score 6):

> An editor made a rather extensive edit of my post that I didn't like

You "not liking" the edit is **not relevant**. What is relevant is that questions are on-topic, not duplicates, clear, focused, specific, understandable, written in English, useful for others, etc. - i.e., the points covered by the close box reasons and by upvote/downvote reasons.

> They removed my summary of the six actions I had tried that didn't work.

In this "summary", one of the things you say you tried that didn't work is "manually inserting `"nth-check": "^2.1.1",` under `dependencies` in `package.json`". But in your self answer, you describe adding `"overrides": { "nth-check": "^2.1.1" }` to the `package.json`, which sounds pretty similar albeit not actually the same thing. So it's not very useful for understanding the question.

We don't actually want questions to contain an explicit "I tried XYZ things and they didn't work" section - **because that un-focuses the question**. It tempts people to identify and answer additional, implicit questions: "Why didn't X work? Why didn't Y work? Why didn't Z work?" *If* it is useful to answer such questions, they should be asked *explicitly and separately*.

We do typically want questions to *illustrate* that you tried XYZ - **not** because it makes you more deserving of an answer (it doesn't, and that's beside the point anyway because this is **not a discussion forum**, and the answer to the question is **not just for you**), but because it **helps to understand** what the question actually is (i.e., to pre-empt simple "have you tried X/Y/Z?" attempts at answering). There are, however, usually much better ways to do this than just saying it. **Show, don't tell**.

And **especially don't do both**. If you are going to show us the result of `npm audit fix` later in the question, don't duplicate the "I tried using `npm audit fix`" message at the start.

> They removed the package.json file I had included, without which it is impossible to reproduce my example (with the exact package version(s) I used).

Several points here.

1. What VLAZ said in the comments (on the question here) about reproducibility. I'm not very familiar with the technology, but I recognize this version-specification syntax (it's also used in the Python ecosystem).
2. What jonrsharpe told you in the comments (on one of your answers here) about reproducibility. I'm not familiar with the technology, but it definitely seems credible that `create-react-app` would fill in a starter/template `package.json` *and that this would be sufficient* for demonstrating the problem.
3. Starting with your initial post, you included a reference link for the concept of a MRE. **Do not do that.** You are putting meta content into the post. **Meta content does not belong in the main space. That is why there is a separate meta site.** By writing something like "... is all it takes to have a minimal, complete and verifiable example." in a question, and linking it to the policy, you come across as bitter that a previous question was rejected for lacking an MRE.
4. A minimal reproducible example should be **minimal**. That means, it **does not** have to reflect the problem you are actually wrestling with in your project ("6 high-severity vulnerabilities"). It needs to reflect the problem **that you need to understand** in order to get things working (i.e., **any one** of those vulnerabilities).
5. The question you are asking is fundamentally a how-to question ("how do I make it do X?"), not a why question ("why does it do Y instead?"). As such, the concept of MRE does not apply strongly. (The corresponding closure reason used to state, emphasis mine: "Questions **seeking debugging help** ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.".) For how-to questions, what we need mainly is a clear, specific, unambiguous **specification** for what needs to happen.

   "force npm install to use nth-check@2.1.1" *seems pretty straightforward to me already.*

> Most of all, they removed the very question I was asking: "How can I *force* `package.json` to use version 2.1.1 of `nth-check`?"

**Factually incorrect**. You had the actual question written twice - the second time, as the fourth section heading (!). This second copy was preserved, because it is *in a place that makes sense for the flow of the edited question*.

---

The edit also made several other changes which you neglected to mention, which are *clearly* positive and in line with policy. In particular:

- It removes excessive formatting: a question should not have sections. Sections belong in answers for questions that are already pushing the limits of what is reasonable to fit into a single, coherent question.
- It [removes noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721/). Especially if you are already worried that the question is long, *what do you hope to accomplish* by writing "This is a long post, but"? Right off the top, **you have increased the length even more**, with content that is **directly contrary to policy**. Please remember that this is **not a discussion forum**, and thus such phrases do not belong in questions or answers (as such, it helps not to think of the question as a "post"). That is just one example of many.
- It removes excessive exposition. **Do not tell us** that you "ran... `npm --version`, which responded `9.6.4`" **unless you have specific reason to believe** that the NPM version is relevant to the problem. *Even then, it would be better to just say "I am running NPM version 9.6.4".* Similarly, do not tell us about how you installed NPM, unless you have a specific reason to believe that something might have gone wrong with the installation. Given that you were able to get NPM to report a version number, and then perform other normal tasks, this seems unlikely.
- It fixes the formatting of the `npm audit fix` results.
- It removes [images of command output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) that are redundant with the text. You should already know not to do this. For one thing, it's right there in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), *in the same bullet-point list that tells you about MREs*. For another, [your immediately previous, recent Meta question was on that exact topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424325)
- It removes a completely useless reference section that duplicates the inline links. How is this supposed to help **understand what the question is**?
- It makes the question **actually readable** inductively (although it is still very long after that heroic effort). Each paragraph leads into the next, rather than it being broken down hierarchically. Again: questions **should not have section headings**. Those are what you use when you want people to be able to jump around, find the specific information they are looking for, and skip the rest.

  That makes sense for answers - because different people with the same question will be missing different conceptual pieces of the puzzle, and not necessarily all of them. It does not make sense for questions because **the entire point of this editing exercise is that the question should contain everything that is necessary to make it answerable, and only those things**. Therefore, people reading questions should not be skipping around in them, should not be tempted to skip around in them (because of the question length), and should not be aided in skipping around (via section headings).

---

Now that I have addressed the substance of the revisions involved in the rollback war, I would like to say a few things about your conduct.

I note that you have rolled back yet again, while you did not at any point make any attempt to improve the rolled-back versions - not even to remove the images, which surely you can clearly see are completely redundant with the text. You also don't seem to be engaging with the other editor in good faith in the comments, and you come across as bitter and sulking about how the question is "not mine any more" - hint: **it was never yours; that is not how the site works**, which is why the automatic CC licensing is necessary.

Then, your reason for rejecting a duplicate closure is that the other question doesn't meet your personal standards for an MRE. **Even if that argument held water** (see above about the necessity for MREs generally), that problem should be fixed by instead editing the target to improve it by adding an MRE (and making sure it is actually minimal). Questions **are still duplicates** if they are substantially still **answering your question** - i.e., explaining to you how to modify `package.json` in order to force NPM to use a specific version of whatever package, according to whatever is special about that package that makes ordinary methods not work.

I also noticed that you deleted your own self-answer for the question after getting into a similar rollback war on that. (The answer you gave matched the accepted answer on one of the proposed duplicates; the same technique is used to solve the same fundamental problem; thus the question is a duplicate.)

Generally speaking, you come across as long-winded, argumentative and egotistical. The way that you have used CW answers on this and your previous Meta question is also rather confusing. It comes across that you are trying to feign some community agreement with you, despite that the votes say otherwise.

Comment: It seems that OP is fond of walls of text. Given the sheer number of things I find wrong with both the question and OP's conduct, I am more than happy to oblige.

Comment: It's not that I think your point is wrong, but the "if I were a moderator you'd be suspended by now" line rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: @Makoto Per my understanding of the purpose of such "cool-down" periods, it is my considered opinion that OP would benefit from one. I acknowledge that it is rather heavy-handed to say so explicitly on Meta, but that also aligns with my understanding of the purpose of Meta.

Comment: It is very seldom that people *value* hearing if someone were in charge that they'd be punished.  I also find it to be quite distracting from the point you want to make, unless the point you want to make is that the OP is in need of discipline or something.

Comment: The point is to highlight the severity of what I am saying... which I guess is essentially the same thing, yeah.

Comment: So this is why it rubs me the wrong way.  I don't want someone who isn't a moderator wagging their finger at me.  You can provide guidance and correction, but you don't get to say or call someone out for being bad.  Like I said, most of the rest of your post is fine, but that sentiment sticks out like a sore thumb and turns what would be relatively OK advice into you sounding like a jerk, which I hope isn't your intent.

Comment: Fair enough. I removed that part now.

Answer (score -10):

The edit changed my post in one very important respect.
It is clear from revision 1 of my post that I want to run `npm install` to automatically create `package-lock.json`.

The question "How can I force NPM to use version 2.1.1 of nth-check?" is much less specific than the two versions of the question that I ask in revision 1. Such a question in no way prevents a solution that makes changes to `package-lock.json` *after* `npm install` has been run.

#### The questions asked in revisions 1 and 2 are fundamentally different.

And in fact, the description retained in revision 2 to run `npm install` no longer makes any sense, because in revision 2 there is no `package.json` without which it is impossible to run `npm install` in the first place.

##### *Revision 2 violates the classical Stack Overflow request to always make sure that what I did [is reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).*

From the above, it is clear that the edit in revision 2 [*deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368734).

Comment: Why are you posting two answers? If you want to change something just edit the old one...

Comment: Why ask a "What should I do?" question only to answer it yourself -- twice?

Comment: I'm not sure if community wiki answers can be deleted by the person who posted them, but if they can, I'd advise you to delete [your original, highly misleading version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424369/3122701) of this answer.

Comment: _"the description retained in revision 2 to run `npm install` no longer makes any sense, because in revision 2 there is no `package.json`"_ - yes there is, `npx create-react-app ...` **creates one**.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz "only to answer it yourself -- twice?" - and then to also act upon that self-determined answer unilaterally.

Comment: "The question "How can I force NPM to use version 2.1.1 of nth-check?" is much less specific than the two versions of the question that I ask in revision 1. Such a question in no way prevents a solution that makes changes to package-lock.json after npm install has been run." Taking this for granted, it is only necessary to re-edit to *clarify that a solution needs to work in a specific way* (i.e., not by editing package-lock.json afterwards). This doesn't justify a rollback.

Comment: The accepted answer for one of the questions you rejected as a duplicate says: "As of NPM v8.3, the correct way to deal with this is via the overrides section of your package.json file." **That is the same conclusion you reached in your own self answer**; thus, the question is clearly a duplicate, and I went ahead and cast the third closure vote.

Answer (score -26):

The edit changed your post in one very important respect.
It is clear from revision 1 of your post that you want to run `npm install` to automatically create `package-lock.json`.

The question "How can I force NPM to use version 2.1.1 of nth-check?" is much less specific than the two versions of the question that you ask in revision 1. Such a question in no way prevents a solution that makes changes to `package-lock.json` *after* `npm install` has been run.

#### The questions asked in revisions 1 and 2 are fundamentally different.

And in fact, the description retained in revision 2 to run `npm install` no longer makes any sense, because in revision 2 there is no `package.json` without which it is impossible to run `npm install` in the first place.

##### *Revision 2 violates the classical Stack Overflow request to always make sure that what you did [is reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).*

Comment: Are you trying to trick us into thinking that this answer wasn't written by you?

Comment: F1Krazy,
as crazy as it may seem, I wrote the answer as if I were addressing the asker (which happens to be myself).
I chose the community wiki form for the answer, as it was meant as an invitation for other users to participate in writing an answer that is helpful to the community.
From what I can tell, nobody has accepted that invitation so far.
Using the I-form in a community wiki answer doesn't make any sense.
Agreed?